# Password field is disabled int network manager vpn

Tags: network-manager, vpn, l2tp

I installed `network-manager-l2tp-gnome` and when I create new L2TP vpn connection the password field does not work

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the question mark on the side of the password field and select
`Store the password only for this user`
or
`Store the password for all users`

Comment: what a terrible UI